# CloudStack unable to add host

Tags: cloud, apache-cloudstack

I am trying to run cloud on my dev server. I followed the detailed guide but each time I get stuck on "add a zone" part. For some reason I cannot add a zone. Below are the logs from cloudstack. I verified sshd_config file to permit root login and firewall is disabled as well. I am on centOS 7, with MySql v5.6 and cloudstack v4.14.

```
2020-11-04 12:17:51,831 WARN  [c.c.a.d.ParamGenericValidationWorker] (qtp1497845528-407:ctx-b69644ac ctx-d3b9d050) (logid:8514bee6) Received unknown parameters for command addHost. Unknown parameters : clustertype
Configure Network ...         [Failed]
2020-11-04 12:21:52,262 WARN  [c.c.a.AlertManagerImpl] (HA-2:ctx-791fbce7) (logid:0382c778) AlertType:: 13 | dataCenterId:: 0 | podId:: 0 | clusterId:: null | message:: No usage server process running
2020-11-04 12:23:12,410 DEBUG [c.c.h.k.d.LibvirtServerDiscoverer] (qtp1497845528-407:ctx-b69644ac ctx-d3b9d050) (logid:8514bee6) Timeout, to wait for the host connecting to mgt svr, assuming it is failed
2020-11-04 12:23:12,413 WARN  [c.c.r.ResourceManagerImpl] (qtp1497845528-407:ctx-b69644ac ctx-d3b9d050) (logid:8514bee6) Unable to find the server resources at http://192.168.1.3
2020-11-04 12:23:12,418 INFO  [c.c.u.e.CSExceptionErrorCode] (qtp1497845528-407:ctx-b69644ac ctx-d3b9d050) (logid:8514bee6) Could not find exception: com.cloud.exception.DiscoveryException in error code list for exceptions
2020-11-04 12:23:12,420 WARN  [o.a.c.a.c.a.h.AddHostCmd] (qtp1497845528-407:ctx-b69644ac ctx-d3b9d050) (logid:8514bee6) Exception: 
com.cloud.exception.DiscoveryException: Unable to add the host
2020-11-04 12:23:12,423 INFO  [c.c.a.ApiServer] (qtp1497845528-407:ctx-b69644ac ctx-d3b9d050) (logid:8514bee6) Unable to add the host
[root@localhost ssh]#
```

Comment: Just ran into something similar myself...investigating

Comment: Relevant docs for my own notes:  [Adding Hosts](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/adminguide/hosts.html)  [Troubleshooting](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/adminguide/troubleshooting.html)

Try rebooting.  At a minimum, I discovered that I had my NFS storage incorrectly mounted and the VM template files weren't accessible.